# Azure tools use wrong certificate for publishing

Tags: azure, certificate

I am developing a Windows Azure Demo Site which uses HTTPS instead of HTTP. So I configured my Azure project to use one self-signed certificate for local development and another (not self-signed) certificate for publishing it into the cloud, just like [this description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203056.aspx) says.

However, whenever I publish my site to the Azure Portal, my development certificate is included instead of the certificate I specified for publishing. Has anyone experienced the same behaviour?

Am I doing something wrong with the certificate or is it a bug? My cert has been issued by the local CA of our own company but not by Thawte or VeriSign or similar, but no warning regarding this is being shown in Visual Studio, so I figured this can't be the problem.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the January 2009 CTP that was fixed in the March 2009 CTP.  Which version of the Windows Azure Tools are you using?

Comment: I really thought I had the most recent version downloaded, which was also true, but then when installing I inadvertently used an old one. Your answer made me check again, thanks.